# to to update table in database using c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

please let us consider following table

[image]

this is done using c#  window form,also let us consider following picture from my sql

[image]

and also

[image]

problem is that when we are adding some data to  form1,it is not saving in database,there is c# code based on which this form is created,my question is what i should add so that it can also update table in sql database?this is sql code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.tatoDataSet1);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tatoDataSet1.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.tatoDataSet1.Table);

        }

        private void tableDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.tableBindingSource.AddNew();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.tableBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.tatoDataSet1);
            MessageBox.Show("information is saved");
        }

        private void კოდიTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you committing the changes to your dataset? this.tatoDataSet1.AcceptChanges();

Comment: i should right?i think it should work correctly right

Comment: It looks like you can also use the dataadapter .Update() method to commit your changes. I'm looking for a reference to the UpdateAll() method that you are using to see if it works the same way.

Comment: please could you post working code?thanks my friend for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this further, you need to add the new row to your table with the values specified in the input form before committing your changes. I added pseudo-code that will guide you. I cannot give the exact code since I do not know the names of all your input fields or database columns. I am assuming that button3_click is your save button.

Then Try committing the changes to your dataset when you click the save button before you apply the update to your adapter:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Create a new row for your table
                dim row as DataRow 
                row = this.tatoDataSet1.tables(0).NewRow 
                ' Add Values to Row here
                ' This is where you will set the values for each column in your rows to the input entered 
                ' Something like:
                dr.Column1 = txtInput1.text;
                ds.tables(0).rows.add(row)
                this.Validate();
                this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.tatoDataSet1.AcceptChanges();
                this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.tatoDataSet1);
                MessageBox.Show("information is saved");
            }
```

Comment: so what i should do first?

Comment: I have no way to test it, update your version of the code, try it out, and let me know.

Comment: ok but what i should do first?when i will enter new data,then click save right?

Comment: I just added that one line to your code to AcceptChanges(), how are you updating the dataset that you are creating?

Comment: i am helping my friend who does not know well  this topic and also english,i dont know what he is doing